# how to skip SASS compilation in Ember Broccoli build

Tags: ember.js, broccolijs

I'm compiling an Ember.js app using broccoli and currently I'm working only on the JavaScript files. The SASS stylesheet files are not being changed at all, yet our Broccoli build is *always* building new CSS out of those stylesheets.

How do I turn this off?

How can I make Broccoli only build JavaScript files or only build SASS files? It's really slowing down my compile times when I change a JS file but a SASS file is compiled.

I'm using ember-cli 0.2.5

Answer (score 2):

update ember-cli to latest version, if you don't change/touch sass files ember-cli does not do any processing/computation on sass files, to turn off sass processing completely if you are not using sass at all, then remove `sass` addon which probably named `ember-cli-sass` from `package.json` and run `npm prune`

Comment: I'm currently stuck on 0.2.5 of ember-cli, we're in the process of upgrading but that isn't complete. is there a nice hack I can use for now to make broccoli ignore that part of the tree?